# Laravel 5.3 Middleware Request Merge Not Return Any Value

Tags: laravel

All my code is working on Laravel 5.2. Now I try to upgrade to Laravel 5.3 it breaks on middleware.

```
// Verify Middleware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // I already make sure the data is exists
    $user = User::find('abc');

    if (!$user) {
        return responseHandler()->unauthorized('Unauthorized');
    }

    $request->merge(['user_id' => $user->id, 'device' => $device]);

    return $next($request);
}

// User Controller
 public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->all());
    $this->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $this->device = $request->device;
}

public function getProfile(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::find($this->user_id);

    $result = Fractal::item($data, new UserTransformer)->getArray();

    return responseHandler()->success(0, $result, 'user');
}
```

The problem is `$this->user_id` is always null. But if I request from getProfile function it return correctly.

`var_dump` result only the login info. it not received any merge request from middleware

On Laravel 5.2 this code is working properly. Any solution?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference-: https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Session In The Constructor

In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use App\User;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class ProjectController extends Controller
{
/**
 * All of the current user's projects.
 */
protected $projects;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

}

Of course, you may also access the request session data or authenticated user by type-hinting the Illuminate\Http\Request class on your controller action:

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't access the session data in Controller constructor because the middleware not run yet.

Refer laravel change log [here](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

> you can't access the session or authenticated user in your
>   controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

In your case you can call session with request object

```
public function getProfile(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::find($request->session()->get('user_id'));

    $result = Fractal::item($data, new UserTransformer)->getArray();

    return responseHandler()->success(0, $result, 'user');
}
```